# Discord.js bot edit embed message with a reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to make my bot through a command to react to an emoji to change the embed message, but I can't get the message to change because I get some errors that I don't understand:

[image]

`TypeError: message.clearReactions is not a function`

```js
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class TestCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'test',
      group: 'asd',
      memberName: 'test',
      description: 'hehe',
      throttling: {
        usages: 1,
        duration: 5
      }
    });
  }

async run(message, args) {
    const prefix = message.guild ? message.guild.commandPrefix : this.client.commandPrefix;
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Messaged testing')
          .setColor("#5d62ff")
          .setDescription('Test embed')
          .setTimestamp();
          message.channel.send(embed)
          .then(message => {
            message.react('➡️');
          const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id === message.author.id;
          const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time:  1500 });   

          collector.on('collect', () => {
            message.clearReactions();

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#007FFF')
        .setDescription('Test #2');

        message.channel.edit(embed);
    });
  })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
};
```

Comment: Try to edit your question and add the errors you received.

Comment: i did it @ZsoltMeszaros you can see it now

Answer (score 0):

If you're using discord.js v12, you can no longer use `message.clearReactions`. You need to use `message.reactions.removeAll()`. You can [check the docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#message) for reference.

```js
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time:  1500 });   

collector.on('collect', () => {
  message.reactions.removeAll();
// ...
```

Comment: Now it gives me `TypeError: message.channel.edit is not a function`

Comment: the bot changes the message when I execute the command and not the emoji

Comment: Can you tell me what you want your bot to do?

Comment: I want when you click the emoji "➡️" the message is automatically edited to another embed